# How to specify subdirectory in Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post, http-headers

It would be nice to do something like this

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://example.com/subdir');
```

It doesn't seem to be working though.

Can it be done ? If so, how ?

The goal is to allow only referrers with `subdir`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging by the [RFC (6454)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6454#section-7.1), it appears you cannot define the Allow Origin in this way. You can define a sub domain, but not a sub directory